# How to rename the same values in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where I want to rename the values that are similar, to go from something like this:

```
{
    33: [3, 4, 6],
    34: [3, 4, 6],
    35: [3, 4, 6],
    99: [7, 8],
    100: [7, 8],
    124: [0, 1, 2, 5],
    125: [0, 1, 2, 5],
    126: [0, 1, 2, 5],
    127: [0, 1, 2, 5]
}
```

I need to go to:

```
{
    33: Cluster1,
    34: Cluster1,
    35: Cluster1,
    99: Cluster2,
    100: Cluster2,
    124: Cluster3,
    125: Cluster3,
    126: Cluster3,
    127: Cluster3
}
```

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Are the names strings? Are they variables representing the former values?

Comment: I think he means variables.

Comment: Yes, the "Cluster1" represents the value of the key "33", which is [3,4,6]; and "Cluster2" will be the replacement of the value [7,8], and so on.

Comment: Go through data and if the value is not seen before add new `Cluster+i` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` and sort the initial dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(str)
counter = 1
s = {33: [3, 4, 6],
34: [3, 4, 6],
35: [3, 4, 6],
99: [7, 8],
100: [7, 8],
124: [0, 1, 2, 5],
125: [0, 1, 2, 5],
126: [0, 1, 2, 5],
127: [0, 1, 2, 5]}
new_s = sorted(s.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])
d1 = new_s[0][-1]
for a, b in new_s:
   if b == d1:
      d[a] = "Cluster{}".format(counter)
      d1 = b
   else:
      d[a] = "Cluster{}".format(counter+1)
      d1 = b
      counter += 1

for a, b in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
   print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
(33, 'Cluster1')
(34, 'Cluster1')
(35, 'Cluster1')
(99, 'Cluster2')
(100, 'Cluster2')
(124, 'Cluster3')
(125, 'Cluster3')
(126, 'Cluster3')
(127, 'Cluster3')
```

Edit:
A more robust solution:

```
s = {9: [49, 50, 51], 10: [49, 50, 51], 11: [49, 50, 51], 13: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 18: [28, 29], 21: [38, 39, 40], 22: [38, 39, 40], 23: [38, 39, 40], 25: [28, 29], 33: [4, 5, 6], 34: [4, 5, 6], 35: [4, 5, 6], 36: [24, 25], 37: [24, 25], 40: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17]}

import itertools
final_dict = {}
for i, a in enumerate([(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]):
   for a1, b1 in a[-1]:
      final_dict[a1] = "Cluster{}".format(i+1)

for a, b in sorted(final_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]):
    print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
(9, 'Cluster6')
(10, 'Cluster6')
(11, 'Cluster6')
(13, 'Cluster2')
(18, 'Cluster4')
(21, 'Cluster5')
(22, 'Cluster5')
(23, 'Cluster5')
(25, 'Cluster4')
(33, 'Cluster1') 
(34, 'Cluster1')
(35, 'Cluster1')
(36, 'Cluster3')
(37, 'Cluster3')
(40, 'Cluster2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, just one question, when I print it "d.items()", what does the last three numbers represents?

dict_items([(33, 'Cluster1'), (34, 'Cluster1'), (35, 'Cluster1'), (99, 'Cluster2'), (100, 'Cluster2'), (124, 'Cluster3'), (125, 'Cluster3'), (126, 'Cluster3'), (127, 'Cluster3'), (1, ''), (2, ''), (3, '')])

Comment: @juanman I am not entirely sure. When I print `d.items()` just after I run this code, I get a regular list of tuples that does not contain `(1, ''), (2, ''), (3, '')`. Did you add additional code to the solution that I posted above?

Comment: Now its ok, it doesn't appear anymore, weird, thanks you very much!

Comment: Ajax, just got into something, when there are not consecutive it aint working, for example `{9: [49, 50, 51],
 10: [49, 50, 51],
 11: [49, 50, 51],
 13: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 18: [28, 29],
 21: [38, 39, 40],
 22: [38, 39, 40],
 23: [38, 39, 40],
 25: [28, 29],
 33: [4, 5, 6],
 34: [4, 5, 6],
 35: [4, 5, 6],
 36: [24, 25],
 37: [24, 25],
 40: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17],` even if they have the same value (13 and 40), as they are not consecutive, they are displayed with different "cluster" ID, do u have any thoughts on this? would appreciate it

Comment: `13 Cluster2
18 Cluster3
21 Cluster4
22 Cluster4
23 Cluster4
25 Cluster5
33 Cluster6
34 Cluster6
35 Cluster6
36 Cluster7
37 Cluster7
40 Cluster8`

Comment: any thoughts? @Ajax1234

Comment: @juanman Sorry for the late response, please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

One thing must pay attention: list is not hashable,
Please check this:

```
my_dict = {33: [3, 4, 6],
           34: [3, 4, 6],
           35: [3, 4, 6],
           99: [7, 8],
           100: [7, 8],
           124: [0, 1, 2, 5],
           125: [0, 1, 2, 5],
           126: [0, 1, 2, 5],
           127: [0, 1, 2, 5]}

# the value of key 33, 34 are different
print(id(my_dict[33]))
print(id(my_dict[34]))


def to_hash_str(my_list):
    from hashlib import sha256
    import json
    return sha256(json.dumps(my_list).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()


clusters_mapping = {to_hash_str(v): v for v in my_dict.values()}

print(clusters_mapping)

new_dict = {k: clusters_mapping[to_hash_str(v)] for k, v in my_dict.items()}

print(new_dict)

# the value of key 33, 34 are same
print(id(new_dict[33]))
print(id(new_dict[34]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

Create an empty `dict`

Create an emplty list to hold values you have seen  `seen`

Loop over the original dictionary, if you meet an item you haven't seen, add it to seen , else continue to the next step

Append the current item to the new dictonary with the original key, and the value being the index of the item in `seen`

Below is the code:

```
seen = []
dct = {}
for k in d:
    if d[k] not in seen:
        seen.append(d[k])
    dct[k] = "Cluster{}".format(seen.index(d[k])+1)
```

Tested and works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = <your dict>
set_dict = list(enumerate(set(tuple(i) for i in d.values()), 1)) 
{ k: 'Cluster' + str([i for i,j in set_dict if list(j) == v][0]) for k,v in d.items() }
```

Output:

```
{33: 'Cluster1',
 34: 'Cluster1',
 35: 'Cluster1',
 99: 'Cluster3',
 100: 'Cluster3',
 124: 'Cluster2',
 125: 'Cluster2',
 126: 'Cluster2',
 127: 'Cluster2'}
```

Comment: Thank you @santhosh, it did the try very well.

Comment: @juanman - btw, you can upvote if you find this answer useful

Comment: unfortunatelly I have already voted for me, and as my reputation at this point is lower than 15 I can't upvote your answer, sorry about that